# spring-boot properties not @Autowired

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to get a Spring-boot application going and I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.  I have a application.properties file at src/main/resources & src/test/resources.   I have an @Bean for my ConfigurationSettings so that I can use them throughout my application:

```
@Component
public class ConfigurationSettings {

private String product;
private String version;
private String copyright;
private String appName;
private String appDescription;
... 
// getters and setters

}
```

Here is how I kick the application off:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.product")
@EnableScheduling
public class OFAC {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run( OFAC.class, args );        
}
```

And here is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.product"})
@PropertySources(value = {@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")})
public class OFAConfiguration {

     @Autowired
     private Environment env;

     @Bean
     public ConfigurationSettings configurationSettings() {
         ConfigurationSettings configurationSettings = new ConfigurationSettings();
         configurationSettings.setAppDescription( env.getRequiredProperty("app.description" ) );
         configurationSettings.setAppName( env.getRequiredProperty( "app.name" ) );
         configurationSettings.setServerPort( env.getRequiredProperty( "server.port" ) );
         return configurationSettings;
    }
```

I am trying to use it in a controller:

```
@RestController
public class AboutController {

   @Autowired
   private ConfigurationSettings configurationSettings;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/about", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public About index() {

     String product = configurationSettings.getProduct();
     String version = configurationSettings.getVersion();
     String copyright = configurationSettings.getCopyright();
    return new About( product, version, copyright );
   }
}
```

However, when step thru this, all the values of ConfigurationSettings are null.   I do have a test that successfully loads the values:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {OFAConfiguration.class})
public class OFAConfigurationTest {
  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;

  @Autowired
  private ConfigurationSettings configurationSettings;

  @Test
  public void testConfigurationLoads() {
    assertNotNull(environment);
    Assert.assertNotNull(configurationSettings);
  }

  @Test
  public void testConfigurationSettingValues() {
     assertEquals("Product Name", configurationSettings.getProduct());
    assertEquals("0.0.1", configurationSettings.getVersion());
    assertEquals("2014 Product", configurationSettings.getCopyright());
 }
```

Can anyone see why the ConfigurationSettings are not being populated in my Controller?

Comment: Is `OFAConfiguration` in package "com.product"? If not then it isn't being loaded into the context.

Comment: N.B. your `@PropertySources` are redundant in a Spring Boot application (be sure to use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` in your tests as well though). Also you have `@EnableConfigurationProperties` which is redundant if you are using `@EnableAutoCOnfiguration`. It might be better to actually use `@ConfigurationProperties` on your `ConfigurationSettings` as well (then you don't have to manually bind it to the environment - up to you).

Comment: You have 2 instances of your `ConfigurationSettings`. One created by the method annotated with `@Bean` and one due to component scanning (it has a `@Component` annotation`). One overrides the other. Remove the `@Component` annotation.

Comment: Good catch. Make that an Answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration leads to 2 instances of the `ConfigurationSettings` class and probably one instance overrides the other.

The 'ConfigurationSettings' has the `@Component` annotation as you are scanning for components (`@ComponentScan`) this will lead to an instance. You also have a `@Bean` annotated method which also leads to an instance. The latter is overridden with the first.

In short remove the `@Component` annotation as that isn't needed because you already have a factory method for this class.

```
public class ConfigurationSettings { ... }
```

You should also remove the `@PropertySource` annotations as Spring-Boot will already load the `application.properties` for you.

Finally you should not use the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation on your test class but the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` and pass in your application class (not your configuration class!).

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=OFAC.class)
public class OFAConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurationSettings configurationSettings;

    @Test
    public void testConfigurationLoads() {
        assertNotNull(environment);
        assertNotNull(configurationSettings);
    }

    @Test
    public void testConfigurationSettingValues() {
        assertEquals("Product Name", configurationSettings.getProduct());
        assertEquals("0.0.1", configurationSettings.getVersion());
        assertEquals("2014 Product", configurationSettings.getCopyright());
    }
```

This will fix your runtime configuration problems and will let your test use the power of Spring Boot to configure your application.

Comment: You were right, I had several conflicting configuration issues and paths going on here.  I never was able to get @SpringApplicationConfiguration to work with the Configuration files, but I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: My test classes were not picking up the application configurations properly. Adding `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead of `@ContextConfiguration` fixed my test classes. Thanks!