# spring boot: unable to autowire bean, but the bean is defined for sure

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I wrote a small spring boot program that needs to connect to a database by using jdbcTemplate. The JDBC driver is present and I set everything in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@servername:1521:foo
spring.datasource.username=guesswho
spring.datasource.password=iwonttell
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

When I let spring boot actuator display the beans by opening localhost:8080/beans I can see my class that needs the bean ...

```
1:Object
bean:"mybean"
scope:"singleton"
type:"de...."
resource:"file [C:/....class]"
dependencies:Array[1]
0:"jdbcTemplate"
```

... and I can see the bean was defined:

```
56:Object
bean:"jdbcTemplate"
scope:"singleton"
type:"org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"
resource:"class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.class]"
dependencies:Array[0]
```

This is my code which shows all three variants of autowiring I tried and none of them works

```
public class myBean implements IMyBean {
  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Autowired
  public myBean(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
  }

  @Autowired
  public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
  }

  @Override
  public foo searchDb(String for) {
    String sql = "SELECT bar FROM ...";

    jdbcTemplate.query( sql, ...
```

In the last line with jdbcTemplate.query a NPE occurs.

I think I'm unable to see the forrest for the trees. I checked the suggested answers stackoverflow provides (e.g. [spring-boot properties not @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138366/spring-boot-properties-not-autowired)) but I think they don't match my problem. Help is wholeheartedly appreciated ...

Comment: can you how the stacktrace, or is it just a null pointer exception given?

Comment: A npe is thrown when I run a method on my class which uses jdbcTemplate

Comment: can you show the code of "myBean" "JdbcTemplate" and the place where you use "mybean"? it would be easier with some code

Comment: Sure. JdbcTemplate is provided by Spring JDBC so I will skip that one.

Comment: I altered my first post and added more code, please have a look at the beginning of the page

Comment: Btw, in general `myBean` should be `MyBean` :)

Comment: and the class wich calls for myBean.searchDb? Also I asume either "myBean" or "IMyBean" are annotated by "@Service" or "@Component"

Comment: by any chance, you wouln't be doins something like "new myBean();" would you?

Comment: You helped me cut down the trees ... In my real code (what I showed above was a cut down version) I forgot one @AutoWired annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a forgotten annotation: @AutoWired was missing and because of this I had two instances. One was configured correctly and included the jdbcTemplate, the other had a null jdbcTemplate.
I checked the first one, but it was not used.