# Unable to resolve name [${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}] as strategy

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have just the rudiments of a spring-boot application in place and i am trying to set up a spring data repository integration test.

This is the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AssetRepository extends CrudRepository<Asset, Long> {
    @Query("select a from Asset a where a.path like :path")
    List<Asset> findAllByPath(@Param("path") String path);
}
```

and the test persistence config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "a.c.a.docmaker.persistence.repository"
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceTestConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersistenceTestConfig.class);

    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${db.use.embeded}")
    private String useEmbeded;

    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;

    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hibernateHbm2DdlAuto;

    @Value("${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}")
    private String hibernateEjbNamingStrategy;

    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;

    @Value("${hibernate.format_sql}")
    private String hibernateFormatSql;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DataSource dataSource = null;
        LOG.debug("url = {}, username = {}", url, username);
        if (useEmbeded=="true") {
            dataSource = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
        } else {
            try {
                WrappedMySqlDataSource mysql = new WrappedMySqlDataSource();
                mysql.setURL(url);
                mysql.setUser(username);
                mysql.setPassword(password);
                dataSource = mysql;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOG.error("Failed to create DataSource, Reason: {}", e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return dataSource;
    }

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("a.c.a.docmaker.persistence.repository");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",
                hibernateHbm2DdlAuto
        );

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy",
                hibernateEjbNamingStrategy
        );

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql",
                hibernateShowSql
        );

        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql",
                hibernateFormatSql
        );

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

The properties are coming from the application.yaml file:

```
server:
  context-path: /docmaker/v0.1

#Database Configuration
db:
  driver: org.h2.Driver
  url: jdbc:h2:mem:datajpa
  username: sa
  password:
  use:
    embedded: true

#Hibernate Configuration
hibernate:
  dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
  hbm2ddl: auto=create-drop
  ejb:
    naming_strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
  show_sql: false
  format_sql: true
```

Finally, here is the repository test that I'm trying to run.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceTestConfig.class})
@TestExecutionListeners({ DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup("assetData.xml")
public class AssetRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private AssetRepository assetRepository;

    @Test
    public void find_NoAssetEntryFound_ShouldReturnNull() {
        Asset assetEntry = assetRepository.findOne(3L);
        assertThat(assetEntry, nullValue());
    }
}
```

When I try to run the test, I find that the application doesn't start up, but fails with the error:

```
15:40:40.007 [main] WARN  o.s.c.s.GenericApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in au.com.auspost.docmaker.PersistenceTestConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}] as strategy [org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}] as strategy [org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.processProperties(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:915) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:835) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
15:40:40.015 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@12d3a4e9: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,persistenceTestConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionAttributeSource,transactionInterceptor,dataSource,entityManagerFactory,org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaRepositoryConfigExtension#0,org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryInterfaceAwareBeanPostProcessor,foo,jpaMappingContext,templateRepository,assetRepository,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator#0]; root of factory hierarchy
15:40:40.044 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DisposableBeanAdapter - Invoking destroy method 'shutdown' on bean with name 'dataSource'
15:40:40.049 [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@63e2203c] to prepare test instance [au.com.auspost.docmaker.persistence.repository.AssetRepositoryIntegrationTest@536aaa8d]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94) ~[spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72) ~[spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212) ~[spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163) [spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67) [junit-rt.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in au.com.auspost.docmaker.PersistenceTestConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}] as strategy [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1566) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~[spring-context-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125) ~[spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60) ~[spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109) ~[spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261) ~[spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68) ~[spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86) ~[spring-test-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}] as strategy [org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:155) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.processProperties(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:915) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:835) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343) ~[spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562) ~[spring-beans-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar:4.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

So there must be something missing in my configuration? or maybe a missing jar file? Can anyone see what's wrong with my work?

**EDIT** - There is a mistake in the yaml file where it reads "hbm2ddl: auto=create-drop" I have corrected it, but it has made no difference to the issue reported.

**EDIT 2** - I have checked and confirmed that org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy is on my classpath, so the StrategySelectionException is not being thrown because of a missing jar (i.e., by a ClassNotFoundException).

***EDIT 3*** - OK, I have been able to go further with this. It seems that the StrategySelectionException is being thrown because because of a failure to find org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy at runtime, i.e., in the scope of the test (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner), not sure why it isn't in teh classpath at this time, I'll keep looking at that.

Comment: looks like the replace of property `${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}` failed.  Are other properties in YAML working fine?

Comment: yes, they are, for example, I get past the hibernate.dialect property.

Answer (score 0):

try using `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead of `@ContextConfiguration`.

Links below :

[Spring Boot issue description : Loading of application.properties does not work in tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/188)

[StackOverflow answer : spring-boot properties not @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138366/spring-boot-properties-not-autowired)

Comment: Also see the reference guide [35. Testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it didn't seem to make a difference. Through one of the other annotation, I must have already been loading the properties. I am resolving other properties, so I rather think that there's an issue with the naming strategy itself.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**
The issue was that I was actually NOT reading my application properties, but a spring boot default set. The reason that this was the case was that the test context was unable to read the application properties at all, and it was necessary to include the application startup in the integration test, thus:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {App.class, PersistenceTestConfig.class })
```

Noting the addition of App. There was also another issue with the setup where I needed to add all of:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
        "a.c.a.docmaker.persistence.repository"
})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "a.c.a.docmaker.persistence.model")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceTestConfig {
```

So not only did I need @EnableJpaRepositories (pointing to the repository classes), but also @EntityScan (pointing to the model classes)