# Spring Boot autoconfig, Hikari datasource fails on pulling properties from yaml file on JUnit

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, yaml, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

It's veri similar to case [33213854]: However I have..

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages= "com.bla.bla")
@Import({RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class, PersistenceContext.class})
public class Main {..}

@Configuration
// Using.. application.yml -------
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource") 
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.aa.bb.repository"})
@EnableTransactionManagement 
public class PersistenceContext extends HikariConfig {

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    return new HikariDataSource(this);
} ..
} ..
```

Hikari datasource is not being filled with the properties during the testing.
The test is..

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {PersistenceContext.class}, 
initializers = {ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class})
public class MyIntegrationTests {

@Autowired
MyRepository repository;

@Test
public void findsSomethingIn() {
    Page<ResourceBundle> bundles= this.repository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 10));
    assertThat(bundles.getTotalElements(), is(greaterThan(20L)));
}
}
```

Application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    jdbcUrl: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/any
    username: uid
    password: xxx
```

However during the test I get..

*IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:784)*

I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: `spring.datasource` is a namespace we already bind to something completely different so I'd avoid using that. Use a namespace of your own. I am confused as what you're trying to do: if you use the standard Spring Boot property, we auto-configure hikari for you already. Why are you defining things that are done automatically by boot?

Comment: Stephane, I supposed the same, everything it would be done by boot, that is not and I want to know why. Main.class is my boot, PersistenceContext.class is my config which should define other kind of AtBeans instead of Hikari datasource, but given that Hikari is not working with properties then I'm trying injecting them "manually".. and that is my concern.. why it's not working on my UnitTest?. So I'll use other namespace, however the documentation says:

Comment: [link] (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database)

Section: 29.1.2 Connection to a production database

Comment: can you share a sample? I fail to see a reason why it wouldn't work in such a unit test.

Comment: I just want to run my unitTest.class using both boot-autoconfiguration and my custom-configuration class which would have BEANs except Hikari-datasource declaration, and to execute unitTest.class using them. Is this possible? (as aforementioned my unitTest.class is not working right now becuase spring-boot is not injecting the properties-values through autoconfiguration). Also I tried with myparams.datasource instead spring.datasource as prefix without success.

Comment: Stephane, this is a concetrated information that I have faced on googling the trouble. (http://www.help-doing.com/sof/26490967.shtml), seems nobody have tried to use Hikari through boot-autoconfiguration.. isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!: Use **@SpringApplicationConfiguration** for Unit-TESTing instead of **@ContextConfiguration** since the test classes were not picking up the application configurations properly .. but WHY?. Reference Case: [22138366](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138366/spring-boot-properties-not-autowired)

Answer (score 0):

For Spring 1.4, I had a very similar issue earlier, solved by adding:
`@EnableAutoConfiguration`
on to the configuration class (in my case it is `DataSourceConfig.class`)

And in the test, tag the test class as follow:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional()
@SpringBootTest(classes = DataSourceConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dao-test")
```

-------- As an example --------

(1) My `DataSourceConfig.class` looks like:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
}
```

(2) And a test class look like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Transactional()
@SpringBootTest(classes = DataSourceConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("dao-test")
public abstract class DaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Test
    ...
}
```

(3) With pom file look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

as wilkinsona mentioned:
"If you want to use HikariCP, simply ensure that Tomcat's connection pool isn't on the classpath and that HikariCP is on the classpath. If you're using spring-boot-starter-jdbc you'll need to exclude tomcat-jdbc, otherwise simply adding a Hikari dependency should be sufficient."

see reference below.

(4) And `resources/application-dao-test.properties` look like this:

```
# PostgreSQL Data Source
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${IT_DOCKER_HOST_IP}:${IT_PG_PORT}/db-name
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
# the config below seems not needed:
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

Reference:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1426
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/03/springboot-working-jdbctemplate.html