# why properties from appliction.properties not available in Junit test in spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, springjunit4classrunner

I have a spring boot application. I am writing Junit tests.
I am trying to inject values from application.properties (defined in src/main/resources/application.properties) and a Status bean configured in AppConfig (src/main/java/hello/AppConfig.java). I see that the bean is autowired (through debugger it is not null) but the values are not set.

Here is application.properties

**src/main/resources/application.propertie**s

```
app.name=rest-service
app.version=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

**src/main/java/hello/AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String version;
    @Value("${app.name}")
    private String name;


    @Bean
    public Status status(){
        return new Status(name,version);
    }

}
```

//Status is a simple pojo with name and version fields

src/test/java/hello/GreetingControllerTests.java

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={hello.TestConfig.class,hello.AppConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class GreetingControllerTests {


    @Autowired
    Environment envi;

    @Autowired
    Status status;

    @Value("${app.name:notConfigured}")
    String appName;

    private String env;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        System.out.println(status.getName());
        System.out.println(appName);
        env=envi.getActiveProfiles()[0];
    }

    @Test
    public void should_fail(){
        if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("DEV")){
            assertThat(false).isFalse();
        }
        if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("QA1")){
            System.out.println("failing the test");
            fail();
        }
    }
}
```

I set debugger in the init method and found that both `appName` and `status` bean with right values set are NOT injected. Status bean is injected though. just the values are not set.

Comment: What does your `Application` class look like?

Comment: You have a miss placed character in the application.properties. The `app.version` doesn't have an `=`

Comment: @ShawnClark: fixing that did not help. you can checkout the code here. https://bitbucket.org/SpringDevSeattle/gs-rest-service

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for sharing the project. It made it a lot easier to work with. Please see my pull request (with comments) to understand how I got it all working.

https://bitbucket.org/SpringDevSeattle/gs-rest-service/pull-requests/4/updating-project-for-spring-boot-14/diff

*** Update *** You had annotations being overwritten due to mixing some old Spring annotations with newer annotations. Credits to [spring-boot properties not @Autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138366/spring-boot-properties-not-autowired) for pointing me to the solution based on a google search for `application.properties not being populated in the environment`.

If you look at the [`@SpringApplicationConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/SpringApplicationConfiguration.html):

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@Documented
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Deprecated
public @interface SpringApplicationConfiguration {
```

It is actually composed of a number of other annotations. The important one is the `@ContextConfiguration`. For the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` it uses a loader and that loader is scanning the classpath for appropriate configuration files along with components to load (one being the thing that reads the application.properties into the environment). Within the test you override that annotation with your declaration:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={hello.TestConfig.class,hello.AppConfig.class})
```

This forces Spring to only load the TestConfig and AppConfig classes without scanning for any other configuration files. Commenting out that annotation and running it will make the test pass and debugging the init() method will show the values injected.

Comment: thank you for taking time to refactor. I appreciate your effort. but I really want to why I wasn't able to inject values from application.properties. if you can help with that, please do. I will merge your pull request but I do want to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: The comments on my pull request explain. Spring Boot 1.4 has changed the way tests are run. You can see that your annotations are deprecated. I could go back and stay with the old 1.3 annotations and try to make it work but seeing as you already set the project up for 1.4 I thought I would show you how to leverage the new stuff.

Comment: Found the issue... updated answer as I can't type it all here.

Comment: great find. thanks. but I have only two config classes (AppConfig and TestConfig). so scanning them should be sufficient correct? what If I want to scan additional TestConfig  to override a bean definition of AppConfig for testing purposes..

Comment: With Spring it isn't just about your `@Configuration` classes. There are a number of other things that are [auto configured](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html) based on what is available on the classpath. For your case of wanting to override things that is still possible with the `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` by doing something like `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { TestConfig.class })`

Comment: so should I include Application.class or not. I mean is this correct? @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes= {Application.class, TestConfig.class})

Comment: I haven't played with that before myself so I can't say for sure. My understanding though is that the loader is still running so it will automatically pickup the Application.class and any other related configurations. You are just telling the loader to use TestConfig.class specifically for some of the beans.

Comment: I tried adding @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class,TestConfig.class}) and it failed "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/web/support/ServletContextApplicationContextInitializer" error

Comment: Not sure then. I would open a new question directed at that issue as the original question was more of an issue with the annotations you were using. Maybe someone else can assist you with how to do that if the context of the question is around it.

Answer (score 1):

You need another property file in the resource directory under your tests.

```
/src/test/resources
```

That's where junit is looking.

Comment: By default, it should be named application-test.properties. If you want to use a different name, you need to use `@TestPropertySource` as well.

Comment: if I have different profiles, for ex application-dev.properties, do I need to have application-dev-test.propeties in src/test/resources?

Comment: by the way, I added application-test.properties in src/test/resources and I still do not see the value injected?

Comment: Try  application.properties

Comment: I tried that. it did not work either. you can browse the code here. https://bitbucket.org/SpringDevSeattle/gs-rest-service/src/a9806c4f77e375667ed279fc20104afb1036382e?at=master